# style a tab widget with strict DOM structure

Tags: html, css

I want to make tab widget and I have below html. This is when tab 1 is selected

```
<div>
    <div class="title active">Tab 1</div>
    <div class="content">Tab 1 content</div>
    <div class="title">Tab 2</div>
</div>
```

if tab 2 is selected the structure will be like this

```
<div>
    <div class="title">Tab 1</div>
    <div class="title active">Tab 2</div>
    <div class="content">Tab 2 content</div>
</div>
```

Is flexbox the right solution for tab styling for above structure? for some reason I don't have right to change the structure.

Even with flexbox I'm stuck, https://jsfiddle.net/dL6j1h54/

How to put the content down?

Comment: So at a time only one container will exist in DOM structure and will set immediate after of selected title?

Comment: @Hanif exactly! that's what make me thought of flexbox's order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox but use `wrap` to allow for forcing elements to start on a new line.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: thin solid darkgray;
}

.content {
  order: 2;
  width: 100%; /* Forces to go to a new line because of flex-wrap */
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="title">Tab 1</div>
  <div class="content">Tab 1 content</div>
  <div class="title">Tab 2</div>
</div>
```